# Creating 10 circles in android

Tags: android

I am trying to create some Circles inside my layout, here is my `drawable.circle` code:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#80FF00FF"
        android:startColor="#FFFF0000" />
</shape>
```

but since I am trying to create 10 of this view and also do some functions on them I can't create them inside my layout file, I want to use array of views - here is what I got so far:

```
private View imageViewArray[];
private Random rand;
private int layoutwidth;
private int layoutheight;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    rand = new Random();
    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    layoutwidth = size.x;
    layoutheight = size.y;
    imageViewArray = new ImageView[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        imageViewArray[i] = new View(this);
        imageViewArray[i].setTag(i);
        randomx = rand.nextInt((layoutwidth - layoutwidth / 3) + layoutwidth / 3);
        randomy = rand.nextInt(layoutheight - layoutheight / 3);
        imageViewArray[i].setX(randomx);
        imageViewArray[i].setY(randomy);
        rlt.addView(imageViewArray[i]);
    }
```

How do I assign Circle.xml to all of these views? `imageViewArray[i].set?`

Comment: use [this method](http://spearhend.blogspot.de/2012/04/load-android-drawable-from-xml.html) to create Drawable from xml file, and then set that Drawable as background to your Views, for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your drawable xml file as background resource to the `ImageView`:

`imageViewArray[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.circle);`

Comment: You can add some paddings `.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom)` to your `ImageView` to reduce the background circle size.

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason not to draw them in the xml, except if the random part is necessary.

Anyway, in order to add views to your main view, create a layout with the circle only. Then inflate it.

```
final View inflatedView = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.your_circle_id, null);
/*Manipulate the inflated view (for example, change location)*/
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_main_layout);
container.addView(inflatedView);
```

I hope that I got you correctly. Change the LinearLayout if it's off a different type.

Answer (score 0):

You should use java graphics classes to do it.